# Running into a race-condition, even with a 'wait'

Tags: bash, wait, race-condition, flush, diskcache

I'm facing a strange race condition in my `bash` program. I tried duplicating it via a simple enough demo program but, obviously, as true for all/most timing-related race demonstration attempts, I couldn't.

Here's an abstracted version of the program that DOES NOT duplicate the issue, but let me still explain:

```
# Abstracted version of the original program
# that is NOT able to demo the race.
#
function foo() {
    local instance=$1

    # [A lot of logic here -
    #  all foreground commands, nothing in the background.]

    echo "$instance: test" > /tmp/foo.$instance.log        
    echo "Instance $instance ended"
}

# Launch the process in background...
#
echo "Launching instance 1"
foo 1 &

# ... and wait for it to complete.
#
echo "Waiting..."
wait
echo "Waiting... done.  (wait exited with: $?)"

# This ls command ALWAYS fails in the real
# program in the 1st while-iteration, complaining about 
# missing files, but works in the 2nd iteration!
#
# It always works in the very 1st while-iteration of the
# abstracted version.
#
while ! ls -l /tmp/foo.*; do
    :
done
```

In my original program (and NOT in the above abstracted version), I do see `Waiting... done. (wait exited with: 0)` on stdout, just as I see in the above version. Yet, the `ls -l` always fails in the original, but always works in the above abstracted version in the very first `while` loop iteration.

Also, the `ls` command fails despite seeing the `Instance 1 ended` message on stdout. The output is:

```
$ ./myProgram
Launching instance 1
Waiting...
Waiting... done. (wait exited with: 0)
Instance 1 ended
ls: cannot access '/tmp/foo.*': No such file or directory
/tmp/foo.1
$
```

I noticed that the while loop can be safely done away with if I put a `sleep 1` right before `ls` in my original program, like so:

```
# This too works in the original program:
sleep 1
ls -l /tmp/foo.*
```

**Question:** Why isn't `wait` working as expected in my original program? Any suggestions to at least help troubleshoot the problem?

I'm using `bash 4.4.19` on Ubuntu 18.04.

**EDIT:** I just also verified that the call to `wait` in the original, failing program is exiting with a status code of `0`.

**EDIT 2:** Shouldn't the `Instance 1 ended` message appear BEFORE `Waiting... done. (wait exited with: 0)`? Could this be a 'flushing problem' with OS' disk-buffer/cache when dealing with background processes in bash?

**EDIT 3:** If instead of the `while` loop or `sleep 1` hacks, I issue a `sync` command, then, voila, it works! But why should I have to do a `sync` in one program but the other?

Comment: Can you place an `echo foo $instance ended` at the end of the functions, to see when they actually end?

Comment: Please [adapt the example code until you can reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We have no way of determining which part of the difference (if any) between the two is responsible for the issue.

Comment: @AlexP When I do that, I get one error from the failed `ls` command in my `while` loop version (`ls: cannot access '/tmp/foo.*': No such file or directory`), followed by `foo 1 ended` message, followed by the `ls` command successfully completing. I'm now launching only 1 `foo` process instead of two.

Comment: @l0b0 If I could adapt and duplicate it, I probably would have no need to come here and ask. I'm only seeking possible suggestions/ideas on what to try next to troubleshoot, and NOT an actual solution.

Comment: Is `/tmp` a regular file system? Can you reproduce the error if you use something else (like your home directory) instead of `/tmp`?

Comment: In my original program, the parent directory of the log file is somewhere under `/home/me/...` only. It is local to the system, and is not a network-share. The filesystem-type is the default, Ubuntu 18.04 `ext4fs`.

Comment: @AlexP Please see my answer below covering the 3 hacks that work. I'm not 100% sure why they work.

Comment: @chepner Please see my answer below covering the 3 hacks that work. I'm not 100% sure why they work.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to start with your original code, and remove bits until you can't reproduce the error. There's probably something in your code that you've left out of your abstract example because you believe it can't possibly be relevant, except that it *is* (or you could reproduce the problem).

Comment: Is there any chance the wait is not running in the original parent process? Could it be running in another `&` spawned sub-shell?

Comment: @chepner A million thanks for encouraging me to do the tedious but the obvious. Namely, removing bits from the original, failing program till it got working again, AND adding bits to my abstracted, working program to get it to fail. In the interest of honesty, let me go ahead and document my stupidity.

Comment: @Jon That was a very close guess, and got me thinking in the right direction, along with the age-old, bit-wise tweaking advice from @chepner. **The Real Problem:** I was starting `foo`, not directly/plainly as shown in my inaccurate abstracted version, but via another `threadStarter` function that, after doing some bookkeeping, would also say `foo 1 &` in its body. And the call to `threadStarter` was itself suffixed with an `&`! So, my `wait` was really waiting on `threadStarter` and not on `foo`. The `sleep`, `sync`, and `while` just bought more time for `foo` to complete, I think.

Comment: Let me add another **EDIT** section to my original question that duplicates the problem, at least on my system. This demo may still be sensitive to timing, scheduling btw, so I can get even the buggy version to work by inserting extra function calls here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that each the following three hacks work, but not quite sure why:

**Hack 1**

```
while ! ls -l /tmp/foo.*; do
    :
done
```

**Hack 2**

```
sleep 1
ls -l /tmp/foo.*
```

**Hack 3**

```
sync
ls -l /tmp/foo.*
```

Could this be a 'flushing problem' with OS' disk-buffer/cache, especially when dealing with background processes, especially in `bash`? In other words, the call to `wait` seems to returning BEFORE it flushes the diskcache (or, BEFORE the OS, on its own realizes and, is done flushing the diskcache).

**EDIT** Thanks to @Jon, his was a very close guess and got me thinking in the right direction, along with the age-old, bit-wise tweaking advice from @chepner.

**The Real Problem:** I was starting `foo`, not directly/plainly as shown in my inaccurate abstracted version in my original question, but via another `launchThread` function that, after doing some bookkeeping, would also say `foo 1 &` in its body. And the call to `launchThread` was itself suffixed with an `&`! So, my `wait` was really waiting on `launchThread` and not on `foo`! The `sleep`, `sync`, and `while` just were helping buy more time for `foo` to complete, which is why introducing them worked. The following is a more accurate demonstration of the problem, even though you may or may not be able to duplicate it on your own system (due to scheduling/timing variance across systems):

```
#!/bin/bash -u

function now() {
    date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
}

function log() {
    echo "$(now) - $@" >> $logDir/log # Line 1
}

function foo() {
    local msg=$1
    log "$msg"
    echo "  foo ended"
}

function launchThread() {
    local f=$1
    shift
    "$f" "$@" &  # Line 2
}

logDir=/tmp/log

/bin/rm -rf "$logDir"
mkdir -p "$logDir"

echo "Launching foo..."
launchThread foo 'message abc' &  # Line 3

echo "Waiting for foo to finish..."
wait
echo "Waiting for foo to finish... done. (wait exited with: $?)"

ls "$logDir"/log*
```

Output of the above buggy program:

```
Launching foo...
Waiting for foo to finish...
Waiting for foo to finish... done. (wait exited with: 0)
  foo ended
ls: cannot access '/tmp/log/log*': No such file or directory
```

If I remove the `&` from EITHER `Line 2` OR from `Line 3`, the program works correctly, with the following as output:

```
Launching foo...
Waiting for foo to finish...
  foo ended
Waiting for foo to finish... done. (wait exited with: 0)
/tmp/log/log
```

The program also works correctly if I remove the `$(now)` part from `Line 1`.

Comment: I'm marking my answer 'tentatively as final', unless someone has an accurate (or, even better) explanation of what's going on. For all we know, this could well be a bug in `bash`.  Thanks to @alexp and @chepner for their time.